# How can I connect to SQL Server and view the data in the database through ASP.NET Web Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to visualize the data which is in the database of SQL Server. For first how am I able to connect my ASP.NET web form to the SQL Server.

I have done: New> project > ASP.NET web application > Web Form 
this is a template which has its own register and login form. In the login how can I use the SQL connection code so that it is able to connect and later I can view the table data.

In my code:

```
protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        // something like this ? 
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyfFrstDataBaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: ref https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_intro.asp

Comment: This is covered in all ASP.NET Webforms tutorials. Including the http://asp.net site itself. It's not something that can be answered in a single answer

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use something like Entity Framework. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data) explains how to use EF with a webforms application.

This will allow you to work with your data in a strongly typed fashion so you won't need to craft a bunch of SQL queries on your own.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sqlhelper.cs file.

Web.config file set connectionstring

Then enter namespace

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
```

Also Add sqlhelper.cs file namespace in asp.net form.